# If I send image path and file name from backend(Spring-boot) as response.And want to download that file on angular with proper authentication?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Angular code

```
this.crmService.getAttachments(complaint_id).subscribe(data => {
    this.imagesArray= data.attachement.images;
    var filesPath=data.attachement.filesPath;
    var fileName=data.attachement.fileName;
    var completePath=filesPath+"\\"+fileName;
    console.log(completePath);
})
```

Now we get the complete path,and I paste this complete path in browser, it opens me the image in another tab but without authentication or privacy. But I want this to be authenticated by a function in angular. Please provide me the solution.

Is there any redirect method (302 redirect) to do this?

My authentication function in angular---

getMultipartOptions() {

```
let token;

if (this.isLoggedIn()) {

  token = StorageService.get("access_token");

  var accessTime = new Date().getTime();

  StorageService.set("last_access_application", JSON.stringify({ time: accessTime }));
  if (this.checkCondition()) {
    this.refreshToken(true);
  }
  return {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    })
  };
}
else {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a way to know on frontend about user's authentication?

Comment: yes sir, I have already made a function to authenticate the user.I have added my authentication function above.

Comment: I think, you can add a new route which matches your image file path and use route guards to resolve or reject that route.